# How to insert data from Google Sheets into HTML Template (dynamic fields)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a newbie and rather a passionate starting to learn programming, than experienced guy.

I have done my research, yet unsuccessful, on how to get data from a Google Sheet and insert cell values into pre-made HTML template.
Task at hand is to generate employees email signatures prepared in HTML. Doing it manually was too time consuming and prone to mistakes.
Any change or update is really painful with this method.

I have found this tutorial and implemented it successfully
https://www.bpwebs.com/pull-data-from-google-sheets-to-html-table

After that I tried to replicate what was working in new project, but no results.
Ideally, expected result would be to run the app and be provided with as many ready HTML files as there are rows in the source Sheet file. There is also one condition, where one of the fields is to be displayed only for some employees (if blank, then insert nothing).

Please note I am very new to javascript, but eager to learn.

EDIT:
I have been asked to share what I have prepared by now. Cannot paste it in comments due to characters limit.
This is the Apps Script that shows simplified version of HTML that I am trying to manipulate. I was able to prepare a JS that changes name and surname as well as controls a portion of scr of img tag.
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx6fapewLMLxgzrRKAY2bybR6HUngoA0sd-CaJHvXxF7TsbByqRWV_4cNpwzPAJJTJvpw/exec
(it should require Google account sing in. Unfortunately, option to share publicly disappeared)

I am also sharing a HTML with script put inside head section (in the Apps Script I have separate 'javascript' file that I am calling in HTML template file)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;600;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
            //I need the var name to be pulling data from the Google Sheets
  var name = 'blank-profile-picture-973460_1280';
  var imgsrc = name;
  document.getElementById('imgSource').src = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/' + imgsrc + '.png';
        var emName = 'Joe';
        var emSurname = 'Doe';
        document.getElementById('Name').innerHTML = emName
        document.getElementById('Surname').innerHTML = emSurname
};
    </script>
    
  </head>
        <body>
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="vertical-align:-webkit-baseline-middle;font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;">
              <tbody>
                  <td>
                      <td valign="middle" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 20px;">
 <span style="margin:0px;font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:800; padding-top:5px;color:black" id="Name" ></span> <span style="margin:0px;font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:800; padding-top:5px;color:#3d85c6" id="Surname"></span><br><img width="158" height="158" min-height="158" min-width="158" max-height="158" max-width="158" src="" id="imgSource">
                    </td>
                  </td>
              </tbody>
        </body>
                  </html>
```

In the article linked above, they are pulling whole table using array. Now I need to either map a whole columns (Name, Surname, img src) or specific cells to pull these values.

Best Regards,
Mac

Comment: Post the scripts and html files you've tried so far and maybe we can spot the problem.

Comment: @TheWizEd I have edited original post and shared the script and HTML

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you've posted doesn't tell me anything about what your problem is.  How do you display the page, custom dialog, sidebar, doPost?  Is the problem you don't know how to build a table in your client html using some of the date from a google spreadsheet?  And there are 2 ways to build the table, pre display of client using templated HTML Service or post using google.script.run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to create a table using both templated HTML and google.script.run

I create a simple spreadsheet as shown.

[image]

Next in Code.gs I create my scripts

```
function showTest() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Test");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(),"Test");
}

function getData() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    values.shift(); // remove header
    return values;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

For templated HTML I create my page HTML_Test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      table, th, td {
        border:1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <? var data = getData(); ?>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?= data[i][0] ?></td>
          <td><?= data[i][1] ?></td>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or using an Immediately Invoked Function HTML_Test

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      table, th, td {
        border:1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="table">
    </table>
    <script>
      ( function () {
          try {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
              function (data) {
                let table = document.getElementById("table");
                for( let i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
                  let row = document.createElement("TR");
                  let cell = document.createElement("TD");
                  let text = document.createTextNode(data[i][0]);
                  cell.appendChild(text);
                  row.appendChild(cell);
                  cell = document.createElement("TD");
                  text = document.createTextNode(data[i][1]);
                  cell.appendChild(text);
                  row.appendChild(cell);
                  table.appendChild(row);
                }
              }
            ).getData();
          }
          catch(err) {
            alert(err);
          }
        }
      )();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the results are

[image]

Reference

- [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#index.html_3)
- [google.script.run()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)